# Постановка кнопок в столбец css

Tags: html, css, mvc

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите, пожалуйста каким образом поставить кнопки в один столбец в css или html в asp.net mvc

[image: страница][image: код кнопок]

Comment: ASP.NET MVC не имеет никакого отношения к вопросу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такое решение:

```css
.bgr {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.button7 {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-top: 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .8em 1em calc(.8em + 3px);
  background: rgb(64,199,129);
  box-shadow: 0 -3px rgb(53,167,110);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgr">
  <a href="@Url/Action("Registation")" class="button7">Registration</a>
  <a href="@Url/Action("Main", "Main")" class="button7">Main Page</a>
</div>
```

Comment: добавил ничего не изменилось

Comment: Покажите HTML и CSS.

Comment: кнопки растянуло по странице но уже столбец)

Comment: Добавьте родителю еще align-items: flex-start;

Comment: снесло текст ближе к левому углу и все кнопка осталась прежней, может показать код фона?

Comment: Так, а вы чего хотите добиться. Объясните тогда подробнее.

Comment: что бы размер кнопки можно было изменить

Comment: Размер кнопки можно изменить через свойство width. Или вам просто нужны кнопки одинаковой длины независимо от количества текста?

Comment: не мне нужно что бы кнопки подстраивались под длину слова, и еще как изменить координаты кнопок

Comment: Я поправил ответ. Позицией меню управляйте при помощи margin у .bgr (например).

Comment: Или можно .bgr добавить position: relative; вместо margin и менять позицию при помощи свойств top и left.

Comment: спасибо большое!